# Why can i declare an array with a predestined size on gcc but not on visual studio c++?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, gcc

i was wondering why i can do this code in linux but not on visual studio?
(File -> main.c)

```
int size;
printf("Size:");
scanf("%d",&size);
int vec[size];
```

Does it have anything to do with c89 or c99 standard? Cause i tried to change the flags on gcc and still worked out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)(*VLA*) is a C99 addition to the standard and [until recently](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) Visual Studio did not support C99  and as far as I know does not support VLA. If you build this in gcc outside of C99 mode let's say in `c90` mode and use the `-pedantic` flag it will provide a warning:

> warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array 'vec' [-Wvla]

`gcc` will support [VLA as an extension outside of C99 mode](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and even in C++.

Note that *C11* made VLA optional, we can see that from the draft C11 standard section `6.10.8.3` *Conditional feature macros* which includes the following bullet:

> **_ _STDC_NO_VLA_ _** The integer constant **1**, intended to indicate that the
>   implementation does not support variable length arrays or variably
>   modified types.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it have anything to do with c89 or c99 standard?

YES!
MSVC doesn't support C99. Variable length arrays are C99 feature.

GCC also allow [VLA as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) so, you can compile your code in C90 mode.

#### 6.19 Arrays of Variable Length

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and **as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++**.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? The latest is 4.8.2 and you code is compiling with warning `C89 forbids variable length array 'vec' [-Wvla]`. This may be a compiler extension.

Comment: @Vcoder You need to use the `-pedantic` to obtain a warning since gcc support VLA as an extension.