# array bound is not an integer constant before is resolved by declaring array inside main

Tags: c++

**program 1**

```
#include <iostream>

std::size_t three() {
    return 3;
}

int i[three()];

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

**program 2**

```
std::size_t three() {
    return 3;
}

int main() 
{
    int i[three()];
    return 0;
}
```

The issue here is Program 1 as expected gives the compilation error

> "error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token"

But I have no idea why the Program 2 is compiled successfully?

Comment: Try `constexpr std::size_t three() { // ...`

Comment: I Know i can use it, But my question is why program 2 is successfully compiled but not program 1.

Comment: Neither is valid C++. Whatever language extension you're using probably has a rule preventing the first.

Comment: I just tested both and both didnt compile on VS2010...

Comment: @Samer That's because no version of VS supports very many C99 features other than the ones that are also part of C++. The OP would get warnings from gcc too if he enables `-Wall` and/or `-pedantic` on gcc/clang

Comment: @Samer [visual studio never supported VLA even in C since until recently, it did not support any C99](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21880957/1708801).

Comment: @Praetorian Actually, `-Wall` [doesn't warn for this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d36ec6628aff1074). You need `-pedantic`.

Comment: Also related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273829/does-int-size-10-yield-a-constant-expression).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C99 allows `int i[three()];` to declare a variable-length array, but only [if it is not of static or thread storage duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360394/declaring-a-variable-length-array-as-a-global-variable-in-c). Declaring it in file scope means that it has static storage duration, so it's illegal even in C99. Declaring it in `main()` the way you did means that it has automatic storage duration, which is allowed in C99.

Some compilers such as GCC and Clang supports it in C89 and C++ modes as well, as an extension. But this is not legal C++ as far as the standard is concerned. Both GCC and Clang will produce a warning for this code if you compile with `-pedantic`.