# How can vector be the return type value and some another question about my code

Tags: c++, algorithm

The following code implements a suffix array algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

/**---  Reference：http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-array-set-1-introduction/ ---*/

/**
 * @brief store the information of suffix
 */
struct suffix
{
    int index;
    string suff;
};

/**
 * @brief get suffix_array
 * @param text
 * @param n the length of text
 *
 * ps:
 *  b a n a n a
 *  5 3 1 0 4 2
 *
 *  0 banana                          5 a
 *  1 anana     Sort the Suffixes     3 ana
 *  2 nana      ---------------->     1 anana
 *  3 ana        alphabetically       0 banana
 *  4 na                              4 na
 *  5 a                               2 nana
 *
 * suffix array for "banana" is {5, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2}
 *
 * Rank array: the rank array rank[i] represents the rank of the suffix 
 *             beginning at the ith position. That is, if suffix_array[i]=j,
 *             then rank[j] = i
 *
 */
vector<int> buildSuffixArray(string& text, int n)
{
    //store suffixes and their indices
    struct suffix suffixes[n];
    vector<int> suffix_array;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++ i)
    {
        suffixes[i].index = i;
        suffixes[i].suff = text.c_str() + i;
    }

    sort(suffixes, suffixes + n, [](struct suffix a, struct suffix b) {
        return strcmp(a.suff.c_str(), b.suff.c_str()) < 0 ? 1 : 0;
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++ i)
        suffix_array[i] = suffixes[i].index;

    return suffix_array;
}

vector<int> rankArray(vector<int>& suffix_array)
{
    vector<int> rank_array(suffix_array.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < suffix_array.size(); i++)
        rank_array[suffix_array[i]] = i;

    return rank_array;
}
```

When I copy this code into Visual Studio, it reminds me that expressions must contain a constant value, and `n`-->(`struct suffix suffixes[n]`) can not be used in this place. The following is the Chinese error message that my compiler reports.

```
表达式必须含有常量值，参数n不可用作常量值
```

I don't understand why, and I can compile it by gcc with no mistake.

And I do not know how `vector` can be the return type value, could someone give me some suggestions?

Comment: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which you attempt to use for `suffixes`. Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: And `vector<int>` is a type like any other, like `string` or `float` or even `suffix`. That's why you can have it as a return type.

Comment: It is considered polite to post code and comments in english. \*hands over a banana\*

Comment: i use c++ with leetcode ,for convenience ，i usuallly use a global variable,lead to has some confusion

Comment: @Swordfish ok ，thanks remind

Comment: @DreamOfCloudy You may keep the banana.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think suffixes is a fixed length ,it is the length of text

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you describe detailed？

Comment: @DreamOfCloudy I'd like it too if the internet was all german and chinese, but, lets face it, we lost the war `:(`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry , I foget convert my annoation to englist

Comment: "I usually use a global variable" - while convenient, be careful with. Limit the number of global variables to the *absolutely necessary*, the more complex your projects get, the more likely you'll run into some issue with the globals...

Comment: @DreamOfCloudy `suffixes` is not a fixed length. Its length is `n` a parameter passed at runtime. Standard C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variable Length Arrays**

> I can compile it by gcc with no mistake.

An array `suffix suffixes[n]` is created on stack with automatic storage duration.
Then this `n` usually must be determined at compile-time in C++.
But some C++ compilers support VLA (variable length arrays) which is a C99 addition and allows declaring C-style arrays on stack with a non constant length.
VC++ does not support C99 and VLA, but [GNU compiler supports VLA as an extension even in C90 and C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).
This is the reason why you can compile the above code by gcc without errors.
There are various related past posts.

- [Why can i declare an array with a predestined size on gcc but not on visual studio c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880922/why-can-i-declare-an-array-with-a-predestined-size-on-gcc-but-not-on-visual-stud)
- [Why does a C/C++ compiler need know the size of an array at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341570/why-does-a-c-c-compiler-need-know-the-size-of-an-array-at-compile-time)
- [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)
- [Variable Length Array (VLA) in C++ compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers)

If you add `-pedantic` (`-pedantic-errors`) option to gcc compile command, we can get warnings (errors) for most gcc extensions.
In this case, with this option we should get following warning (error) message:

> ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'suffixes'

---

**Implementation of `buildSuffixArray`**

> And I do not know how vector can be the return type value

Your `buildSuffixArray` goes to segmentation fault even in GNU compilers because `suffix_array` is not allocated.
The following minimally fixed version will work fine **with GNU compilers**:

```
std::vector<int> buildSuffixArray(const std::string& text, int n)
{
    suffix suffixes[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++ i)
    {        
        suffixes[i].index = i;
        suffixes[i].suff = text.c_str() + i;
    }

    std::sort(suffixes, suffixes + n, [](struct suffix a, struct suffix b) {
        return std::strcmp(a.suff.c_str(), b.suff.c_str()) < 0 ? 1 : 0;
    });

    std::vector<int> suffix_array(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++ i){
        suffix_array[i] = suffixes[i].index;
    }

    return suffix_array;
}
```

But VC++ does not support VLA and the above fixed version still shows compile error with VC++.
The following code is an example avoiding VLA (, redundant argument `n` and lambda expression).
This will work fine with both gcc and VC++.
[**DEMO is here.**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Lxb6cEljXwmUJ1vB)

```
std::vector<int> buildSuffixArray(const std::string& text)
{
    std::vector<suffix> suffixes(text.length());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < suffixes.size(); ++i)
    {        
        suffixes[i].index = i;
        suffixes[i].suff = text.c_str() + i;
    }

    std::sort(suffixes.begin(), suffixes.end(), [](const suffix& a, const suffix& b) {
        return (std::strcmp(a.suff.c_str(), b.suff.c_str()) < 0);
    });

    std::vector<int> suffix_array(text.length());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < suffix_array.size(); ++i){
        suffix_array[i] = suffixes[i].index;
    }

    return suffix_array;
}
```